# How can I access the text of notes in a ppt file via applescript?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I'd like to get the text of notes in a PPT file on os x. I feel like this should work:

```
get content of notes page of slide N of active presentation
```

But it always returns a "missing value". Any thoughts?

Incidentally, my goal is to be able to create a new version of a set of slides where the notes don't contain the text STUDENT=HIDE... I like providing slides to students, but don't always want them to see everything in advance (e.g. the correct result of an in-class exercise).

Comment: Needed to say that someone made a free python app for removing instructor notes from powerpoint mac 2011.  Very cool: http://andrewfong.com/blog/2011/10/04/remove-notes-from-powerpoint-pptx/comment-page-2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notes are in the shapes (`place holder` class --> `text frame` --> `text range` --> **content**).

Here is an example of how to get value of the note in each slide :

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    repeat with tSlide in (get slides of active presentation)
        set tNote to ""
        repeat with t_shape in (get shapes of notes page of tSlide)
            tell t_shape to if has text frame then tell its text frame to if has text then
                set tNote to content of its text range -- get the note of this slide
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        if tNote does not contain "STUDENT=HIDE" then
            --- *** do something with tSlide *** ---
            --
            --
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in awarding the answer... I didn't get a notification about this as I was expecting.